# Text correction

Tags: learning, questions

I am learning Esperanto since january and I am kinda starting to understand how it works, but I am doing this project from school where I needed to write a text about me since the project is learning this language. Can someone please help me correct it? If possible I would like to then contact someone that can help me privately. Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Welcome to Esperanto StackExchange. We prefer questions that have a general response that help everybody rather than individual requests for help so this question is a bit off-topic. You might have more luck asking on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/esperanto or Telegram https://t.me/joinchat/AZriqT4BBWtvcGWiQgBO6A

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this answer for people that might have the same problem, even though I am incapable to help you personally.

For general help in grammar checking, there are several solutions:

- A free, online, [Esperanto grammar checker](http://beta.visl.sdu.dk/lingvohelpilo/#)
- Find someone in the Esperanto community in a forum or chatroom (as Neil said in the comment, [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Esperanto/) and [Telegram](https://t.me/joinchat/AZriqT4BBWtvcGWiQgBO6A) are good places to start )
- Find Esperantist language buddies near you with [Amikumu](https://amikumu.com/)
- Use UEA's [association finder](https://www.uea.org/landoj) to find a near organization, and ask them
- Find a *paid* teacher/tutor through services like [italki](https://www.italki.com/teachers/esperanto)